# sort and retrieve differently composed data from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have this small test dataset:

```
date1 = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17) 
date2 = datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 13) 
date3 = datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 10)
date4 = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 12)
date5 = datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 3)
date6 = datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 7)
date7 = datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 5)
date8 = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 12)
date9 = datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 12)
date10 = datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 1)
date11 = datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 23)
date12 = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 12)
date13 = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 23)

data = {'CustomerId' : ['c001', 'c002', 'c002', 'c003', 'c004', 'c005', 'c006',
                    'c003', 'c003', 'c007', 'c008', 'c005', 'c007'],
   'Type' : ['OV', 'OV', 'work', 'OV', 'OV', 'work', 'work',
             'work', 'work', 'OV', 'work', 'work', 'work'],
   'ElCr' : [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   'PlVr' : [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
   'Date' : [date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6, date7, date8, date9, date10, date11, date12, date13]
   }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to compile different information together and have failed in making something work completely. I also suspect that I am doing things in a very little efficient way.

My main goal is to figure out how many, and which CustomerIds, have reported ‘1’ in the PlVr column, after having reported ‘OV’ in the Type column at an earlier date.

For these customers, I also need to know if they reported ‘1’ in the PlVr column or ‘1’ in the ElCr column when they reported ‘OV’ in the Type column at that earlier date. I must differentiate on PlVr and ElCr.

I have tried the following:

```
df_grouped = df.sort_values('Date').groupby('CustomerId')

for customer_id, group in df_grouped:
    ov_mask = group['Type'] == 'OV'
    plvr_mask = group['PlVr'] == 1

    if ov_mask.any() and plvr_mask.any() and (ov_mask.idxmax() < plvr_mask.idxmax()):
        print(f"Customer {customer_id} first reported 'OV' and then reported '1' under 'PlVr'.")
```

It seems to work, but I am not sure that I am not missing anything with this code. I also lack the last information I need, and I am not sure how to solve it.

I should also summarize and report this data in some way that does not require a lot of manual work to read. Grateful for any tips and tricks!